# delete images from firebase storage

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-storage

sometimes I upload images from my application to firebase storage and I put the URLS in firebase firestore
and sometimes I put the URLS manually from random links in firebase  firestore that's its not in my storage
so when I want to Delete the item in firestore its only deleted if the images in my storage

```
deleteItem(id) async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('sss').doc(id).delete();
    setState(() {});
  }

  deleteimage(url) async {
     await FirebaseStorage.instance.refFromURL(url).delete();
    setState(() {});
  }

Future<void> deletefun(images) async {
    for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
      var imageUrl = await deleteimage(images[i]);
    }
  }
```

and the code of button to delete

```
ElevatedButton(
 onPressed: () async {
                                                  
   if (data['imgurl'].isNotEmpty) {
      await deletefun(
 data['imgurl']); }            
await deleteItem(data.id);                                                                                                    
},
 child: const Text('delete'),
),}
```

Comment: What is not working as you expect? Do you get an error? In other words, what is your exact problem?

Comment: when there is no image in fire storage i got Null error

Answer (score 0):

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: ()async{
 FirebaseStorage ref = FirebaseStorage.instance;
        var file = await ref.ref('CoverImages/1657860002431.jpg');
        await file.delete().then((value) => print("File Deleted Successfully"));
      },),
```